# Render a "long" video (> 2 mins) in one step, without running out of memory

Tags: rendering, video, memory-management

I feel like I am missing something fundamental. Here is my problem: I am producing videos (10-30 minutes each), using the Video Sequence Editor – there is no 3D modeling involved here, just stitching together a few video clips (mp4 files).

If I try to render the complete video, Blender crashes. I could track the problem down by monitoring memory while rendering: After starting, memory usage increases slowly but steadily, eventually starts to swap and then Blender crashes.

As a workaround, I started to render only 3000 frames (2 minutes). I then stich the segments together with ffmpeg. This works, but requires a lot of clicking.

So my question: Am I missing something? How can I render more than 2 minutes of video in one step?

PS: I found some answers pointing to faulty plug-ins, but I am using stock Blender without any additions, on Linux (Mint). The machine has 12 GB memory.

**System Details**

- Blender Version: 2.76b
- Installation Source: Standard Repository (universe)
- OS: Linux Mint 18 64 bit (4.4.0-64-generic)
- System Memory: 12GB

Comment: This is not intended behavior, no application should crash, ever. If it is running out of memory then something is wrong. If you can recreate it reliably and provide an example file you should file a bug report

Comment: what version of blender and what OS. Blender did have a memory leak in the VSE in the recent past IIRC

Comment: Thanks folks, I just added version information. I just checked the release notes and realized that my version is well over a year old. I'll try installing the latest version. (I guess I am relying on OS repositories too much.)

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: I was using an old version of Blender with a memory leak (thanks @3pointedit for pointing me in the right direction!).

I just installed 2.78c, and this version does not have the problem any more.

Just a note that as of March 2017, 2.76b was the latest version in the Linux Mint repository (and probably also in the Ubuntu repository).